# The fastest way to detect if a double is finite?

Tags: c#, .net, il

What is the fastest way to detect whether a `double` value is a finite value (neither NaN nor positive/negative infinity) in IL without throwing an exception?

I was considering the following approaches (c# notation for reader's convenience only, in my project I'm using IL for this):

1. `!double.IsNaN(x) && !double.IsInfinity(x)` - the most obvious and, probably, the slowest because 2 method calls are involved.
2. `(*(((long*) &x)) & 0x7fffffffffffffffL) < 0x7ff0000000000000L`

or in IL:

```
  ldloca x
  conv.u 
  ldind.i8 
  ldc.i8 0x7fffffffffffffff
  and 
  ldc.i8 0x7ff0000000000000
  clt
```

My questions about the second approach are:

1. According to my research, this should precisely determine whether any given `x` is finite. Is this true?
2. Is it the best possible way (performance-wise) to solve the task in IL, or is there a better (faster) solution?

P.S. I do appreciate recommendations to run my own benchmarks and find out, and will most certainly do this. Just thought maybe someone already had similar problem and knows the answer.
P.P.S. Yes, I realize that we are talking abot nanoseconds here, and yes, they are important for my particular case

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Microsoft use [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,b3843db5f359a0fd):

```
public unsafe static bool IsNaN(double d)
{
    return (*(UInt64*)(&d) & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL) > 0x7FF0000000000000L;
}
```

And [this](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,db0603318ee4c493):

```
public unsafe static bool IsInfinity(double d) 
{
    return (*(long*)(&d) & 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF) == 0x7FF0000000000000;
}
```

Unless the use of `!double.IsNaN(x) && !double.IsInfinity(x)` is the **real** bottleneck of your program, which I doubt, I recommend you to use theses functions, they will be easier to read and maintain.

Comment: put ``(*(((long*) &x)) & 0x7fffffffffffffffL) < 0x7ff0000000000000L`` in an ``inline``d function, and be happy.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman yes, he could, but if the OP is not the only one to maintain the code, he's got to write a *very, very, very* good comment...

Comment: Yes, indeed. Unless required just stick to the given .NET framework methods.

Comment: @Binkan Salaryman - performance is more important in this case vs. readability of the code. Thanks for your answer and comments.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman C# doesn't have the `inline` keyword. (Though the JIT compiler does inline when it thinks it's the better option.)

Comment: @svick well, it seems it [is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Thomas: Yes, I meant the ``MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining`` option.

Answer (score 4):

Without **unsafe** context and mixing **NaN**, **+Inf**, **-Inf** values:

```
var isFinite = ((BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d) >> 52) & 0x7ff) != 0x7ff;
```

Explanation:

A double is a 64 bits value stored as:

- 1 bit for the **sign**
- 11 bits for the **exponent**
- 52 bits for the **mantissa**

```
Bit No:  63  62~~~~~~~52  51~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~0
Bit:      0  00000000000  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
       sign   exponent                         mantissa

If sign = 0 && exponent == 11111111111 && mantissa == 0   =>   +Infinity
If sign = 1 && exponent == 11111111111 && mantissa == 0   =>   -Infinity
If             exponent == 11111111111 && mantissa != 0   =>   NaN
If             exponent != 11111111111                    =>   Finite

In other terms:
If exponent == 11111111111   =>   Not finite
If exponent != 11111111111   =>   Finite

Step 1: Convert double as Int64 bits (DoubleToInt64Bits)
Step 2: Shift right 52 bits to remove mantissa (>> 52)
Step 3: Mask exponent bits to remove sign (& 0x7ff)
Step 4: Check if all remaining bits are set to 1

Note: 0b11111111111 = 0x7ff = 2047
```

Finally, this can be **simplified to**:

```
var isFinite = (BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d) & 0x7ff0000000000000) != 0x7ff0000000000000;
```

In **extension method** and **unsafe** context:

```
internal static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static unsafe bool IsFinite(this double d) => (*(long*)&d & 0x7ff0000000000000) != 0x7ff0000000000000;
}
```

**Tests**:

```
Console.WriteLine("NegativeInfinity is " + (double.NegativeInfinity.IsFinite() ? "finite" : "not finite"));
Console.WriteLine("PositiveInfinity is " + (double.PositiveInfinity.IsFinite() ? "finite" : "not finite"));
Console.WriteLine("NaN is " + (double.NaN.IsFinite() ? "finite" : "not finite"));
Console.WriteLine("Epsilon is " + (double.Epsilon.IsFinite() ? "finite" : "not finite"));
Console.WriteLine("MinValue is " + (double.MinValue.IsFinite() ? "finite" : "not finite"));
Console.WriteLine("MaxValue is " + (double.MaxValue.IsFinite() ? "finite" : "not finite"));
```

**Result**:

```
NegativeInfinity is not finite
PositiveInfinity is not finite
NaN is not finite
Epsilon is finite
MinValue is finite
MaxValue is finite
```

Answer (score 3):

A good alternative without unsafe would be:

```
public static bool IsFinite(double value)
{
    return (value > double.NegativeInfinity && value < double.PositiveInfinity);
}
```

Comment: OP clarifies what is meant to be an finite number (`neither NaN nor positive/negative infinity`). I totally agree with that definition, so false for NaN is correct for me.

Answer (score -1):

I would follow how Microsoft implemented it seems suitable for me:

```
    public static bool IsFinite(double d)
    {
        ulong bits = BitConverter.DoubleToUInt64Bits(d);
        return (~bits & PositiveInfinityBits) != 0;
    }
```

https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Double.cs,169